# Controlling speed of animation as point animates across line

Tags: javascript, math, geojson, turfjs

I am trying to control the speed of an animation so it matches the actual speed that a vehicle took.

```
let counter = 0;
const animate = () => {
    counter += 1;

    // Update point geometry to a new position based on the animation
    // And the distance the point has travelled along the route.

    const updatedPoint = turf.along(lineString, (counter / 100) * lineDistance, 'kilometers');
    moveVehicleToPoint(updatedPoint);

    // updatedPoint represents a point between/along between origin and destination

    if (updatedPoint.geometry.coordinates[0] !== destination) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}

animate();
```

I'm nearly there but maths isn't my strongest asset.

`lineDistance` is roughly 0.01-0.02km on average.
`lineString` contains the start and end coordinate.
`turf.along` take the `lineString`, a set distance, and returns the distance from the start to your provided distance along the line in kilometers.

Currently, I've included an arbitrary value of 100 to divide by. If the vehicle move took 1 second, this is pretty good. It will move along to the next point by roughly a second.

If it took 2 seconds, it'll be too slow, and finish moving well before the vehicle would have.

How can I include my `durationSeconds` variable, so that if I say it took 2 seconds, the `animate()` will perfectly animate along the line over 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a variable in the outer scope that relates to the speed you need. Change it's value accordingly to control it.

Comment: Hi Saddam, thanks for your answer & welcome to S/O. Please could you try and include a code sample in relation to my question so that I can better understand your solution? I did mention the `durationSeconds` variable in the question, but I am unsure how to implement this to control the speed.